# Help in making node with OpenCV/cv_bridge and ROS Indigo

Tags: ros, opencv, opencv2, libopencv, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,

Running `ROS Indigo`, `Ubuntu 14.04` and `catkin_simple`. My system has downloaded:
`libopencv-dev` and `ros-indigo-cv-bridge`

I am trying to make a package that uses opencv's mouse button events. After making the package, I got the following errors related to opencv:

```
home/menon/juan/ros_workspace/hku_drc_class_sysu/catkin/src/vision_stack/steer_fitting/src/patch_select.cpp: In function \u2018void mouse_callback(int, int, int, int, void*)\u2019:
/home/menon/juan/ros_workspace/hku_drc_class_sysu/catkin/src/vision_stack/steer_fitting/src/patch_select.cpp:188:14: error: \u2018CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN\u2019 was not declared in this scope
         case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
              ^
/home/menon/juan/ros_workspace/hku_drc_class_sysu/catkin/src/vision_stack/steer_fitting/src/patch_select.cpp:197:14: error: \u2018CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP\u2019 was not declared in this scope
         case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
              ^
/home/menon/juan/ros_workspace/hku_drc_class_sysu/catkin/src/vision_stack/steer_fitting/src/patch_select.cpp: In function \u2018void onMouse(int, int, int, int, void*)\u2019:
/home/menon/juan/ros_workspace/hku_drc_class_sysu/catkin/src/vision_stack/steer_fitting/src/patch_select.cpp:489:18: error: \u2018CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN\u2019 was not declared in this scope
     if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
                  ^
/home/menon/juan/ros_workspace/hku_drc_class_sysu/catkin/src/vision_stack/steer_fitting/src/patch_select.cpp: In function \u2018int main(int, char**)\u2019:
/home/menon/juan/ros_workspace/hku_drc_class_sysu/catkin/src/vision_stack/steer_fitting/src/patch_select.cpp:613:36: error: \u2018CV_WINDOW_NORMAL\u2019 was not declared in this scope
         namedWindow("image_window",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL); //window for openCV displays
                                    ^
make[2]: *** [vision_stack/steer_fitting/CMakeFiles/patch_select.dir/src/patch_select.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [vision_stack/steer_fitting/CMakeFiles/patch_select.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Invoking "make -j20 -l20" failed
Failed to build catkin packages!
```

My package.xml contains the following opencv related dependencies:

```
  <build_depend>opencv2</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>
  <build_depend>image_transport</build_depend>

  <run_depend>opencv2</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cv_bridge</run_depend>
  <run_depend>image_transport</run_depend>
```

And my CMakeLists.txt looks as follows (patch_select is the node that uses opencv):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(steer_fitting)

find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

catkin_simple()

# Executables
cs_add_executable(valve_fitting src/valve_fitting.cpp)
cs_add_executable(patch_select src/patch_select.cpp)

target_link_libraries(valve_fitting ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(patch_select ${OpenCV_LIBS})

cs_install()
cs_export()
```

And finally, these are the #includes in my code:

```
// OpenCV includes
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h> // don't need the transport headers for this routine; 
#include <image_transport/subscriber_filter.h>

#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
...
using namespace cv;
```

I have read the migration guide and looked for others online, including this post: (http://answers.ros.org/question/185105/add-opencv-to-indigo/) but still not sure how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202810/help-in-making-node-with-opencv/cv_bridge-and-ros-indigo/) by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-10**:
Are those all of the errors? I would either expect that you are unable to find a particular header (it would be the first error) or that you haven't included a header that you need. Either way I don't see anything `catkin` or `catkin_simple` related that would cause these compile errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realized that the definition of the events had been modified/updated.

Instead of being: `CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN`, they are now defined as: `EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN`.

After making these modifications, everything built and compiled fine.

---

Originally posted by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) with karma: 208 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2